# not well-ordered iff. erratum?

Tags: set-theory

I’m reading Michael O’Leary’s A first course in mathematical Logic and Set Theory. Page 185 says:

```
Theorem 4.3.29
(A,⋞) is not a well-ordered set if and only if (A,⋞) does not have a decreasing subset.
```

it’s that ok?
i think that it should be “(A,⋞) is not a well-ordered set if and only if (A,⋞) have a decreasing subset.” A = {0,1/2,1/3,1/4,1/5,...} is not well-ordered because {1/2,1/3,1/4,1/5,...} is decreasing. i’m wrong?

Comment: You are correct: the statement would be correct if either one of the two *not*s were deleted, assuming that *decreasing subset* means *infinite strictly decreasing subset*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott that is only assuming that we assume linear ordering

Comment: @ℋolo: True, though context suggests that at that point the author is dealing with linear orders. If it were partial orders, I’d expect the author to be singling out well-founded ones, for instance.